# Solr & Suggestions - When does the search engine generate (build) suggestions

Tags: solr, search-suggestion

When does `Solr` (v4) generate or build its suggestions (when `indexing` or when `searching`)?

Because, I dont understand the two options `buildOnCommit` & `buildOnOptimize` in Solr? Which of the two is the best (in speed and efficiency) to use?

And, in the configuration file `solrconfig.xml`, is there a parameter to adjust `tolerance` in order to have multiple suggestions even if the number of different letters between the `query` & the `suggestion` is equal to `four` ?

Comment: can you give examples of required "tolerance"?

Comment: For example, when I type `renou` it gets me `renault` even if there are other words which are closer.

Comment: Can you give an example of "closer" words?

Comment: The suggestion it's giving for the query: `renou` is `rendu`, but I wish to have `renault` too, but maybe I'm asking for too much, because the suggestion it's giving me is closer, but I wonder if it can be more tolerant and give me more suggestions?

Comment: I've updated the answer: try to set `spellcheck.alternativeTermCount=1000` and then decrease this number to make the search faster.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this property this weekend and I'll give you the result returned.

Comment: Do I need to re-index when I change `spellcheck.alternativeTermCount` value?

Comment: No, it is the number of hypotheses to read from the existent index.

Comment: It's not changing the results I'm getting. I dont know if my index is too small but almost every query return only one suggestion. I think that this configuration is too rigid.

Comment: It's hard to discuss this topic in general. If you make a separate question out of your second question and give the spellchecker configuration, it will be easier to give exact answers.

Comment: I have posted my question is a separate thread: [Multiple suggestions by query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874157/solr-how-to-obtain-multiple-suggestions-for-a-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildOnOptimize` is practically useless, you can optimize your index only manually from the admin panel, for example. `buildOnCommit` will rebuild your suggestions index too often (depending on the `hardCommit` settings in `solrconfig.xml`). It is better to rebuild suggestions manually using cron jobs by adding [`spellcheck.build=true`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#spellcheck.build) to the spellcheck handler.

Try to increase [`spellcheck.count`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#spellcheck.count) and set [`spellcheck.onlyMorePopular=false`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#spellcheck.onlyMorePopular) to show more suggestions.

If you still receive less results, than `spellcheck.count` try to increase [`spellcheck.alternativeTermCount`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#spellcheck.alternativeTermCount) (the bigger the slower).

Comment: Thanks for details about how to get more result, but I'm affraid that won't get me more results. Because `spellcheck.count` is equal to 10, and changing `spellcheck.onlyMorePopular` to false havent gotten me more suggestions. **P.S:** I have modified the `/spell` request handler.